# how to find the column index using the row index and cell value in grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am creating a dynamic gridview which has dynamic link buttons on click of which i am capturing rowindex and column index. I am able to capture rowindex and cell value but not the column index... i guess i can do that by cell index but then how to find cell index... please help i am searching this from hours...

```
protected void GDVReports_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            LinkButton myLink = new LinkButton();
            myLink.Click += ViewDetails;


            if (cell.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                while (cell.Controls.Count > 0)
                {

                    myLink.Controls.Add(cell.Controls[0]);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                myLink.Text = cell.Text;


            }
            cell.Controls.Add(myLink);

        }
    }
}



protected void ViewDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    LinkButton lnkView = (sender as LinkButton);
    GridViewRow row = (lnkView.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
   string id = lnkView.CommandArgument;
   string b = row.DataItemIndex.ToString();

    int d=Convert.ToInt16(b);
    string r = //to find cell index
     rowname = GDVReports.Rows[d].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
     string columnIndex = GDVReports.Rows[d].Cells[r].Text.ToString();
    int c = Convert.ToInt32(columnIndex);
    columnname = GDVReports.HeaderRow.Cells[c].Text.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells have a propoerty named ColumnIndex, if its applicable...
If you have only cell value, search columns inside a given row for the one matching your value...

Comment: it is a dynamic gridview... i am getting row index and column value on click of any column... but i am not able to capture the column index... and column index is not applicable in gridview... it is not data gridview

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, GridView doesn't provides a property: `ColumnIndex` for any of it events or anywhere else.

Why not create your own logic to extract the Cell Index based on the `ID` of the `LinkButton` clicked. Below is a sample code to help you get started.

```
LinkButton lnkView = (sender as LinkButton); // This button was clicked
GridViewRow row = (lnkView.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
int cellIndex = 0;
foreach( TableCell cell in row.Cells)
{
  if(cell.FindControl(lnkView.ID) !=null)
       break;
  else
       cellIndex++;
}
```

// Now `cellIndex` has the index of Column where the `LinkButton` was clicked,
// So get the Column name

```
columnname = GDVReports.HeaderRow.Cells[cellIndex].Text.ToString();
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. getting this error

Comment: instead of using ID is there any other way we can find out the control? because i guess ID is not generated...

Comment: Well... ID is the unique property of any Control on a webpage. I will suggest you to make a little change in your dynamic control generation to assign unique IDs as well to any Linkbuttons. This is indeed a standard practice. May be this link can help you on using IDs:  http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamic-Controls-Made-Easy-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Also  at which line you got Object Reference error ?